# regex to break a string into "key" / "value" pairs when # of pairs is variable?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 1.9 and I'm wondering if there's a simple regex way to do this.

I have many strings that look like some variation of this:

```
str = "Allocation:  Random, Control:  Active Control, Endpoint Classification:  Safety Study, Intervention Model:  Parallel Assignment, Masking:  Double Blind (Subject, Caregiver, Investigator, Outcomes Assessor), Primary Purpose:  Treatment"
```

The idea is that I'd like to break this string into its functional components

- Allocation: Random
- Control: Active Control
- Endpoint Classification: Safety Study
- Intervention Model: Parallel Assignment
- Masking: Double Blind (Subject, Caregiver, Investigator, Outcomes, Assessor)
- Primary Purpose: Treatment

The "syntax" of the string is that there is a **"key"** which consists of one or more "words or other characters" (e.g. Intervention Model) followed by a colon (:).  Each key has a corresponding **"value"** (e.g., Parallel Assignment) that immediately follows the colon (:)…The "value" consists of words, commas (whatever), but the end of the "value" is signaled by a comma.

***The # of key/value pairs is variable.*** I'm also assuming that colons (:) aren't allowed to be part of the "value" and that commas (,) aren't allowed to be part of the "key".

One would think that there is a "regexy" way to break this into its component pieces, but my attempt at making an appropriate matching regex only picks up the first key/value pair and I'm not sure how to capture the others.  Any thoughts on how to capture the other matches?

```
 regex = /(([^,]+?): ([^:]+?,))+?/
=> /(([^,]+?): ([^:]+?,))+?/
irb(main):139:0> str = "Allocation:  Random, Control:  Active Control, Endpoint Classification:  Safety Study, Intervention Model:  Parallel Assignment, Masking:  Double Blind (Subject, Caregiver, Investigator, Outcomes Assessor), Primary Purpose:  Treatment"
=> "Allocation:  Random, Control:  Active Control, Endpoint Classification:  Safety Study, Intervention Model:  Parallel Assignment, Masking:  Double Blind (Subject, Caregiver, Investigator, Outcomes Assessor), Primary Purpose:  Treatment"
irb(main):140:0> str.match regex
=> #<MatchData "Allocation:  Random," 1:"Allocation:  Random," 2:"Allocation" 3:" Random,">
irb(main):141:0> $1
=> "Allocation:  Random,"
irb(main):142:0> $2
=> "Allocation"
irb(main):143:0> $3
=> " Random,"
irb(main):144:0> $4
=> nil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
irb(main):003:0> pp Hash[ *str.split(/\s*([^,]+:)\s+/)[1..-1] ]
{"Allocation:"=>"Random,",
 "Control:"=>"Active Control,",
 "Endpoint Classification:"=>"Safety Study,",
 "Intervention Model:"=>"Parallel Assignment,",
 "Masking:"=>
  "Double Blind (Subject, Caregiver, Investigator, Outcomes Assessor),",
 "Primary Purpose:"=>"Treatment"}
```

The whitespace parts of the regex aren't needed, but help to slightly clean up the output. I leave it to you to do followup minor cleanup, such as removing the colons from the end of the keys or trailing commas from the values.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to work, but I don't completely understand it. The method-call to split.(/\s*([^,]+:)\s+/), basically says "find the key and split off of it", right? If so, how/why does "split" then transfer the key into the array? Ok, so I think I learned something new about the split method.  If I do str.split(/:/), I don't get the colons in the array.  If I do str.split(/(:)/), I **get** the colons in the array???  Should this have been obvious?  I ask b/c it doesn't seem obvious from the rdoc.

Comment: Yes, capturing groups are included in the results. By putting the `\s*` and `\s+` outside the group, they are not included. Excerpted from `ri String#split`: _"If pattern is a Regexp, str is divided where the pattern matches. Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into individual characters. **If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well**."_

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I managed to get the following to work on your example string and regex:

```
str.split(/((?:[^,]+?): (?:[^:]+?,(?![^\(]+?\))))+?/).delete_if(&:empty?).map{|s| s.strip.chomp(',')}
```

I had to add a lookahead to ensure that the commas inside any parenthesis would be ignored, as well as muting some of the groups. The `delete_if` and `map` at the end are purely cosmetic.